# Tomcat home page is not opening in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, tomcat

I have configured tomcat 7.0.47 in my mac and started it (bin/startup.sh). When I tried to open the URL: `http://localhost:8080` in Chrome, it threw an error: The requested URL could not be retrieved. Same case with Firefox.

However when I opened this in Safari it worked without any issues. What is happening here? This is a very strange. Any help would be mightily appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the IP of your machine if any or `127.0.0.1:8080`

Open `/etc/hosts` file  and check if you see an entry like

```
 127.0.0.1  localhost
```

If the above entry is not there in the hosts file add it to map localhost to 127.0.0.1

where ever localhost comes other than 127.0.0.1 line like

```
 ::1 localhost 
 ca71::2%lo0    localhost
```

rename it to ip-6-localhost, those are IP6 settings/address format.

Comment: Hi, I tried 127.0.0.1 and localhost and both are not working. The above mentioned line is present in /etc/hosts. And IP is working fine. IP:8080 is displaying the page. Contents of /etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
ca71::2%lo0 localhost

Comment: do you have a # before the above line in /etc/hosts file ? if so remove it. Please copy paste the content of hosts file here.

Comment: This line is not commented out (if that is the question). There are some # in previous lines. The same URL is working in Safari and not on Chrome and Firefox.

Contents of the file:
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
ca71::2%lo0 localhost

Comment: where ever localhost comes other than 127.0.0.1 line rename it to ip-6-localhost. save and try once. guess that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the solution was to add localhost and 127.0.0.1 to the proxy's exception list (bypass). After doing that, Chrome finally showed the little stylish Tom - the cat.